# Does std::thread call pthread_create

Tags: c++, pthreads, c++11, std

I am using gcc 4.6.1, but will be using other compilers as well. My question is: Does std::thread call pthread_create?

The background is, that i want to use a library which overloads pthread_create.

Thank you

Comment: On POSIX platforms it's highly likely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::thread` is not required to call any particular underlying thread library. Implementations of the standard library are free to use whatever they want, so long as their behavior matches the standard. If a standard library ships with a compiler for a specific platform, that standard library implementation may directly call OS functions.

Remember: use of the standard library is portable. *Implementations* of it don't have to be.

Comment: It _can_ use OS-specific calls?

Comment: @ildjarn: Internally, yes. It's got to call *something* that talks to the OS, whether directly or indirectly. Standard library *implementations* are not necessarily portable.

Comment: Sorry, the phrasing confused me -- it sounds like you're saying the standard can mandate OS-specific implementations.